# Why glassfish behave differently in using maven dependency from a raw Java EE project?

Tags: maven, glassfish, dependencies, javax.imageio

I have been struggling on this issue for about one wholly day, and I think I really need some help now.

Things begins that the `ImageIo` package for java don't support a `webp` format image. So I found [this project](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio) and get things worked in my private lib package. In the meanwhile, since my project solving dependency by using maven, and seems that, that particular project was not hosted by the central maven repository yet, so I upload this jar of that `webp-imageio` to my private maven repository. So that I can happily involve that dependency in pom.xml and make a whole package(of `DataDriver`) in order to finally using it in my glassfish project. like this:

```
<groupId>com.foo.service</groupId>
<artifactId>DataDriver</artifactId>
<version>3.7.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bitbucket.luciad</groupId>
      <artifactId>webp-imageio</artifactId>
      <version>0.4</version>
      <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
...
```

I do a unit test for the `DataDriver` I wrote, and seems work fine. Frankly, I even don't know why I add a jar and the suddenly `ImageIo` package can magically work with `webp` now? Some Run time loading? But now I can deal with a `webp` image and I can carry on working with glassfish to deal with a `webp` image now. But when I came to work with glassfish, it doesn't work. Just give me a exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(ServiceRegistry.java:825)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:528)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:513)
    at com.foo.service.datadriver.db.image.ImageSaver.imageType(ImageSaver.java:30)
    at com.foo.service.datadriver.db.image.ImageSaver.save(ImageSaver.java:42)
```

And the snippet of the particular code which cause this exception was(in `DataDriver`):

```
private String imageType(byte[] inputByte){
        ImageInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputByte));

            Iterator<ImageReader> iterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(inputStream);
            ImageReader imageReader = iterator.next();
            return imageReader.getFormatName();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I tried same data in the unit test again, and I works just fine, then I try to build a Java EE project to do a test with same data, things also worked just fine. This will only happen when I use my `DataDriver` (which was packaged with the `webp-imageio` I download from the project formerly mentioned and hosted on my private maven repo) with glassfish.

I think there should be something to do with the glassfish, maybe some dependency issue? But I really don't know how to do a further debug.

Answer (score 2):

> Frankly, I even don't know why I add a jar and the suddenly `ImageIO` package can magically work with `webp` now?

I'll answer this question first, because it is directly related to the problems you are experiencing.

The reason this works, is because `ImageIO` internally uses a service lookup mechanism, that scans the class path for service providers. The `WEBP` plugin you are using implements the abstract `ImageReaderSpi` class, and the JAR file contains a resource `javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi`, that refers to this (`com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebPImageReaderSpi`) implementation.

You can read more about the registry and the lookup mechanism in the [IIORegistry API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/IIORegistry.html).

The scan for plugins is usually done only on class initialization. This is likely the main reason you don't have the reader available in the server version, and a very common problem: `ImageIO` is already initialized when your application starts.

The way I see it, you have at least two options:

- Either declare your dependency with scope `provided`, and install the webp plugin (*and any transitive dependencies it might have*) into GlassFish's shared or common lib folder. This will make sure the plugin classes are available when `ImageIO` is initialized.
- Or, if you prefer packaging the webp plugin as part of your app follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app). It involves adding a web context listener, that registers and un-registers plugins at runtime, whenever your application is started or stopped.

PS: I realize that the `WEBP` plugin has native dependencies. You need to install them as well, and make sure that the application has the access privileges to load native code.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement haraldK great answer, there's also another alternative to force ImageIOto scan for plugins. You just have to call a method called... ImageIO.scanForPlugins(). 
You can put it on a ApplicationStartedListener or whatever other place you'll call only once.

Comment: Just be aware that by doing this in your *application*, you have just created a resource leak, and restarting your application may no longer work reliably. Unless you also remember to unregister the plugins you found during the scan when your application stops. The web context listener I mention above, does all of this for you.

Comment: Thanks @haraldK! I tried your listener but it didn't work for me at the time. I don't remember exactly what happened tho, I just remember I could still not read the webps without my solution.

Comment: Well, my listener does (nothing but) `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` when the application starts... So it should work just the same. But it *also* remembers what plugins were registered locally, and makes sure they are unregistered when your application is stopped/destroyed to avoid the memory/resource leak I mentioned.